# Check if time range doesn't collide with another datetime range

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My user inputs two values in datetime [html form] fields :: book_from f.e 2015-09-15 16:44:39 book_to 2015-09-17 16:44:39 then the query should check if the provided dates doesn't collide with a existing reservation.

My query looks as following - but I feel like there is no way for it to work.

```
A raw php code -> "SELECT * FROM `tbl_rezerwacje` WHERE '".$_POST['book_from']."' between `date_from` and `date_to`  AND `nr_sali` = '".$place."'";

SQL dump -> SELECT * FROM `tbl_rezerwacje` WHERE '2015-09-15 16:44:39' between `date_from` and `date_to` AND `nr_sali` = 'F115'
```

Answer (score 4):

`WHERE` expects to have a colum name after it and not a value.
Also `between` does not work that way.

**EDIT:** Strawberry's explanation

Consider the following

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

A |---|

B    |-----|

C            |----|

D   |-----------|
```

The test for overlaps is simpler than Szenis seems to appreciate.

Event B overlaps event A because event B starts before event A ends, and ends after event A starts.

Event C does NOT overlap event B because although event C ends after event B starts, it starts after event B ends

Event D overlaps all the other events because event D starts before all of the other events end, and ends after all the other events start.

So the test for overlaps is simply:

```
y_start < x_end AND y_end > x_start
```

**The answer**
Thanks to Strawberry the answer is much shorter then before

```
SELECT * 
FROM `your_table`
WHERE (`date_from` < end_date AND
       `date_to` > start_date) AND 
       `nr_sali` = your_book_id
```

If there is a record found the book is not available during the given dates.

Comment: r MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2015-09-15 16:44:39') OR `date_to` > Convert(datetime,'2015-09-17 16:44:39')) A' at line 3

Comment: For sure the or has to be AND, let me check few more times if it works properly

Comment: which of the datas are mysql values and which of them are user provided can you show me?

Comment: @Szenis , please remove the link to w3fools. That site, especially the SQL part, is full of errors and inconsistencies. For the rest, +1!.

Answer (score 0):

$from_date -> user input of start date
$to_date -> user input of end date
'start' -> DB colum for start date
'end' -> DB column for end date

ANSWER

SELECT * 
FROM `table_reservations`
WHERE `start` < "$to_date" AND
       `end` > "$from_date"

If a record matches this query then it overlaps another booking (you have to validate that the daterange from the user is valid -> `$from_date < $to_date`)